# No devices found with name or id matching 'emulator-5554' even though the Flutter doctor is OK

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

When I run my program on the emulator the console shows this:

> No devices found with name or id matching 'emulator-5554'

The Flutter doctor is OK. How do I fix this?

```
C:\Users\athir>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.928], locale en- 
US)
• Flutter version 2.2.1 at C:\flutter
• Framework revision 02c026b03c (2 weeks ago), 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
• Engine revision 0fdb562ac8
• Dart version 2.13.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at \Users\athir\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) 
(emulator)
• Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.101
• Edge (web)                  • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.41

• No issues found!
```

[image]

Comment: Go to device manager in android studio, wipe the data, delete all the devices which are available and add new device again.

Comment: same publem   No devices found with name or id matching 'emulator-5554'

Comment: Does it shows you the emulator in the tool bar in android studio after you created the new virtual device?

Comment: Yes, it show.![Valid XHTML](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ioth-project.appspot.com/o/Annotation%202021-06-12%20101643.png?alt=media&token=d36d1930-2a0f-41b4-9834-616f14f031b5).

Comment: Thanks you I fix it so resetting a flutter doctor -v in android studio terminal

Comment: Welcome, finally it worked. Congrats

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error just recently. My own exact error was "No devices found with name or id matching 0DE9E241-5554-4D27-BAE5-7839B1FB1206". For anyone who faces such an error, I realized it was due to a folder that I guess was generated by vscode. A folder called .vscode in the project folder, inside that folder includes a launch.json file. In there you'll find a "configurations" key that houses an array of objects, check for the key "deviceId" and its value in the array, if that value matches the id you got in your error, comment out the whole code in that file and try running your app again. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, I have resolved it just by downloading the developer profile for the iOS device on which I was trying to build the application.

Steps -

1- Check your iOS device version

2- Go to - https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport

3- Download the developer profile according to your iOS OS Version.

4- Unzip the downloaded file and paste the folder into /Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

To achieve the 4th step,
Goto Applications -> Right Click Xcode -> Click on Show Package Contents
Now follow - /Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport

5- Restart your Xcode

Cheers, all set.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem after updating iOS physical device.
Updating MacOS and XCode solved the problem